# SKMaps Annotation order (z index)

Tags: ios, z-index, skmaps

I'm using SKMaps and have some problem with SKAnnotation.
How to work with z-index of SKAnnotation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution for this. We are also waiting for a solution from Skobbler team. The bringAnnotationToFront only works temporarily for the selected annotation. If you select another annotation, the original annotation will return to its original zIndex. I have tried to group my annotations whereby i draw each set separately, it does not work either and it seems the pins have random zIndex.

Hopefully, Skobbler Team build this new feature soon.